# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2^{\sqrt{n}}}$ converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2^{\sqrt{n}}}$$

Here are my ideas $$\frac1{2^{\sqrt{n}}}\gt \frac1{2^{n}}$$

and
$$\frac1{2^{n}}\gt\frac1{n!}$$

But i don't know what to do with them. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Just show that $2^\sqrt{n}\geq n^2$ for big values of $n$ and you are done

Comment: Okay, but how do i show it. I have very limited set of tools I can use. Maybe induction?

Comment: If you know how to evaluate a limit, then that should suffice.

Comment: (to prevent you from wasting your energy in the future, if $\text{something}(n)>2^{-n}$, then of course $\text{something}(n)>\frac1{n!}$ )

Comment: Exponential function raises faster so $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^{\sqrt{n}}}{n^2}\ge 1$$ ?

Comment: Use the p-series test: http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/p-series.html

Comment: FWIW, using numerical methods (Richardson extrapolation) this series appears to converge to 3.7882192306479539510..., the [ISC](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc) found nothing for this value.

Comment: Btw: induction should work too. Just assume there exists an $n_0$ such that the exponential is greater than the quadratic, show this implies the same for all greater integers, then find $n_0$

Comment: @b00nheT's idea above is, until now, the best one on the page by far. So, the task is to prove that $2^{\sqrt{n}}>n^2$ for every $n$ large enough, or, equivalently, that $2^x>(x^2)^2=x^4$ for every $x$ large enough, or, equivalently, that $x\log2>4\log x$ for every $x$ large enough... Done?

Comment: Note that this is *definitely* a duplicate. Naive searching through the "close" button yields nothing, but I've seen this question asked multiple times... Yesterday in fact,  if my memory doesn't fail me

Answer (score 3):

The [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) tell us that $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{t}}}dt\stackrel{u=\sqrt{t}}{=}2\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{u}{2^{u}}du
 $$ $$\stackrel{IBP}{=}\frac{1}{\log\left(2\right)}+\frac{2}{\log\left(2\right)}\int_{1}^{\infty}2^{-u}du=\frac{1+\log\left(2\right)}{\log^{2}\left(2\right)}$$ so the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

It's

$\displaystyle 0<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+1}{2^n}=2\cdot 2 +1=5$

because of $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=m^2}^{(m+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}<\frac{2m+1}{2^\sqrt{m^2}}$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially what @user90369 wrote, shown a bit differently:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2^{\sqrt{n}}}=\\\underbrace{\frac1{2^{1}}+\frac1{2^{\sqrt2}}+\frac1{2^{\sqrt3}}}_{3\rm{ \, terms}}+\underbrace{\frac1{2^{2}}+\cdots+\frac1{2^{\sqrt8}}}_{5\rm{ \, terms}}+\underbrace{\frac1{2^{3}}+\cdots+\frac1{2^{\sqrt{15}}}}_{7\rm{ \, terms}}+\cdots\\< \frac3{2^1}+\frac5{2^2}+\frac7{2^3}+\cdots.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try using Cauchy's root test.

Let $a_{n}=\frac{1}{2^\sqrt{n}}$, then $a_{n}^\frac{1}{n}=\dfrac{1}{2^\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=2^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$. Now, convince yourself that $a_{n}^\frac{1}{n}$ is lesser than $2^{-\frac{1}{n}}$, which in turn is less than $1$. This means, by Cauchy's root test that $\exists$ k $\in$ $\mathbb R$ such that $a_{n}^\frac{1}{n}<k<1$, and hence the series converges.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong to the core since $a_n^{1/n}\to1$. (@upvoter Do you understand what you vote about, or are you a bot?)

Answer (score 0):

Claim: $1/2^{\sqrt n} \le 1/n^2$ for large $n.$ If the claim is true, then our series converges by the comparison test. Proof of claim: It's the same as saying $\sqrt n\ln (1/2) \le -2\ln n,$ or $\sqrt n \ge (-2/\ln (1/2))\ln n.$ The last is true for large $n,$ since any positive power of $n$ eventually overtakes any positive constant times $\ln n.$